# Azure Devops Release pipeline variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Azure dev ops release pipeline for deploying a static web app to Azure.The problem I am encountering is that I am not able to pass the variable to the Azure Static Web Apps api token, but rather hardcode the value in the form field as shown below.

**1) Below solution is what I am trying to achieve, but doesn't work:**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

**2) Below solution is working fine, but I don't want to follow this approach:**

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the value of `$(deployment_token)` in a [Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) and link that variable group to the pipeline. Since this is a sensitive token, you can also click the lock icon to mark it as secret.

Another option is to add it as a [Pipeline Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) directly on the pipeline.